# Build a dynamic URL on anchor tag click - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a table of several anchor tags. I want to create an external URL dynamically on clicking each anchor tag. I tried using [routerLink] but it is getting the base URL appended. Is there any angular way of doing it ? Any help is much appreciated.

html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="invoiceNo">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Invoice # </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let invoice"> 
            <a [routerLink]="getInvoiceUrl()"  target="_blank">
              {{invoice.invoiceNumber}}
            </a>
          </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

ts

```
 getInvoiceUrl(){

return "www.google.com";
```

}

Comment: Hi, JavaLearner. Have you find the solution? I have similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

yes, just use href:

```
<a [href]="getInvoiceUrl()">
```

Make sure you include http: else it will include the domain.

so:

```
return "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: One issue is I want to create the link dynamically on. So when I add the function call in href.it is giving me bad response error. When I try to add it in (click) event again that is error .....Any suggestions.`<a (click)="{{getInvoiceUrl(invoice.filePath)}}" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 2):

public link="public"

use this in a tag --> [href]=link> {{ link }}

It will redirect to www.localhost:4200/public

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your own routes if you are using **`routerLink`**, in your case just use [href]

```
<a href="{{getInvoiceUrl()}}">Link</a>
```

Comment: One issue is I want to create the link dynamically on. So when I add the function call in href.it is giving me bad response error. When I try to add it in (click) event again that is error .....Any suggestions.`<a (click)="{{getInvoiceUrl(invoice.filePath)}}" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0):

Could you use something other than an anchor tag - like perhaps have:

```
<span (click)="takeMeToDynamicUrl()">link text</span>
```

And then your method can create the URL and use any numb er of available methods to take you to the URL e.g.

```
document.location.href = 'https://dynamicallycreatedurl.com';
```

Comment: that way the dom node lost "<a>" styling and behaviour.