# Is it possible to build a dynamic URL in text with Angular 7

Tags: angular

I want to create an URL dynamically when clicking on link in comment. Is there any method achieving this?

[test code on stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjxmrg)

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<div [innerHTML]="Text"></div>`,
   })

   export class AppComponent  {

      DokumentID: 5

      Text = `The attached document can be found on this link.
              <br><br>
             <a [href]="DokumentOpen(DokumentID)" target="_blank">test.pdf</a>.
             `

      DokumentOpen(DokumentID: number): string{ 
          return "docs/load?"+DokumentID
      }

    }
```

Comment: can you put your text directly on template? Also you may want to have a click event handler instead of use href attribute on your link. Then you can use router API to achieve redirection.(or window.open if a new window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: This is not duplicate of Angular HTML binding. Before I wrote my question, I looked at all related questions including this. There is a real duplicate of my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51640982/build-a-dynamic-url-on-anchor-tag-click-angular-5  But It has no accepted and correct answer.

Comment: these text including href produced by user as an comment. The href in these text refers to document link produced and controlled by same service. It is easy to use static lick in text as The attached document can be found on this link <a href='docs/load?8923' target='_blank'>test.pdf</a> . The document id produced by the service is order number. So it easy to manipulate the system. That's why I want to change the link in text dynamically before open the document in browse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding innerHtml, then putting text in it and then expecting Angular to treat it as Angular directives. Why the complexity?

Why not just do this?

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
          selector: 'my-app',
          template: `<div>`The attached document can be found on this link.
                  <br><br>
                 <a routerLink="docs/load?{DocumentID}" target="_blank">test.pdf</a></div>`,
       })

       export class AppComponent  {
          DocumentID: 5
        }
}
```

Comment: At first it was easy to put link into comment. After the idea of dynamically encrypting the document numbers used in the link, it become more complicated. 
If I can't find the solution, I will do as you say.

Comment: Give. E more context on what exactly you are trying to achieve and I might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: As far as I understand, usage of the dynamic link in text is not easy. Is it possible to use routerLink in text as an alternative?

Comment: Using "dymanic" text as you called it is complicated in Angular based directives because Angular safeguards binding text to directives by getting rid of any HTML. Using routerLink in text that you then bind will have the same limitation.

Comment: Hi Richards,  Thank you for your interest.  I have a comment table in the database. The comment table has an mediumtext field for user comment. User can add dokument (generally pdf) link that is related to document table. I use [innerHTML] in div to show these comment on the related page. When user click an a document link in comment, ı show these document in another tab in the browser.  This system works well now. But ı want to change the document id in the link before open the link  due  to safety reasons.

Comment: Like I guess. I think, I have to add a document id to the comment table. Then I produce the angular template rendered text in the page.

Comment: You can take the text from the comment table and use some regular expressions to extract the document ID or the full link, then do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create like below:

```
 <a href="{{downloadURL}}/File/{{fileName}}" id="upload" download="{{fileName}}" target="_self" role="link" class="btn btn-link" >
                      {{ fileName }}
                  </a>
downloadURL = '';
this.downloadURL = environment.apiURL; 
// you can hardcode or take from the enviornment.
```

Comment: this technique works in template. But it not work for link in text. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvqupq

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholders. Also, format the query string properly.

```
return `docs/load?id=${DokumentID}`;
```

Note the backticks.

This could also be done in the service method using `HttpParams`.

Comment: I have applied your suggestion. Unfortunately not. Test code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mlrux